# uninterrupted setInterval function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to display some divs on my HTML page with some animations. So I decided to use the setInterval method to increases the opacity of all of my div. I wrote the below code in order to do this (the toggleAll function is run at the beginning)

```
var tab = ["lien","contact","comp_info","comp_langue","apropos","loisir","etudes","exp_pro","projet"];

function increaseOpacityDiv(id,opacityMax){
    console.log("fonction appelée : increaseOpacityDiv, opacity max :"+opacityMax);
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.opacity >= opacityMax){
        console.log("entré ! ");
        clearInterval(boucle);
        document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = opacityMax;
        debugger;
    }else{
        recup = parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).style.opacity+0) + 0.01;
        document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = recup;
    }
} 
 

function decreaseOpacityDiv(id){
    console.log("fonction appelée : decreaseOpacityDiv");
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.opacity <= 0){
        clearInterval(boucle);
        document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = 0;
    }else{
        recup = parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).style.opacity) - 0.01;
        document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = recup;
    }
}


function toggleAll(){
    console.log("fonction appelée : toggleAll");
    if(all){
        console.log("faire disparaitre");
        for (var i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
            boucle = setInterval(decreaseOpacityDiv,5,tab[i]);
        }
        all=0;
    }else{
        console.log("faire apparaitre");
        for (var i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
            boucle = setInterval(increaseOpacityDiv,5,tab[i],1);
        }
        all=1;
    }
}
```

It works, the browser displays correctly the divs. However I can't disappeared them, in the same way as I displayed them. I found out that my toggleAll function made a lot of setInterval and I can't stop all of them, so the increaseOpacityDiv is run like every 5ms. And the clearInterval method can just stop the last loop made by the setInterval, not the others. This is shown by this below :
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L39Rq.png)

Do you know a way I can show my divs then stop all the setInterval ?

Comment: You could use requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval to improve performance.

Comment: Don't use JS for something that you don't have to. I would use a CSS animation.

Comment: You should not use setInterval to make animations. You have some options: Either use a library like animeJs oder gsap, set `transition: opacity .5s ease;` via css and simply set your target value via javascript, or create your own callback look - so a method which calls itself with `requestAnimationFrame` - but that is probably out of your capability as you need to make your own easing and keep track of states - no offense :)

Comment: You're using the same variable `boucle` for all the intervals. At the end of the loop it just contains the last interval. You could put them in an array.

Comment: I used js because I didn't know we can specify a target element on a transition property. I thought it was just applied on the selector. How can I modify it to put all of my divs in ?